# Adding sleep before API returned the data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one API it takes sometime to return the data from the Db, meantime I'm getting 504 error. Is there anyway to add sleep before getting the response? I tried below code, but with in few seconds getting 504 issue.   Please suggest me.

```
this.http
            .get("/testAPI/testAPIData", { params })
            .pipe(timeout(500000)) 
            .subscribe(
              (res) => {
                if (res.hasOwnProperty("errorMessage")) {
                  $("#idErrorMessage").html(
                    "<tr><td colspan='5'><b>No data available</b></td></tr>"
                  );             
                  this.dtTrigger.next();
                } else {
                  this.results = res;
                  this.dtTrigger.next();
                }
              },
              (err) => {
                console.log("Error While Loading the Table  ::: " + err.error);
              }
            );
        }
```

Comment: **1.** There is _no_ way to induce a delay for an HTTP req. from front-end. Most browsers have a set timeout for requests. **2.** If the HTTP req. takes long to respond, then it isn't good design. Standard practice is to return a Location header in initial request, ping it continuously to check if data is ready and finally fetch it. **3.** Mixing Angular with JQuery will lead to maintenance issues in the long run. Most if not all that could be done with JQuery could be accomplished in native Angular.

Answer (score 0):

### use debounceTime()

I think you are trying to reduce the number of HTTP calls

I will recoument to user **debounceTime(1000)** from rxjs

### Example

```
import {  debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

this.http.get("/testAPI/testAPIData", { params })
            .pipe(debounceTime(1000)) 
            .subscribe(
              (res) => {
               ...
              },
              (err) => {
               ...
              }
            );
        }
```

this function will collect stream and take call each after 1sec, not with each stream.

for more read the documentation: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime